# Stop Audio with Bootstrap Modal

Tags: jquery, html, bootstrap-modal

I am using html5 audio contained within a bootstrap modal window. When closing the modal the audio continues to play if audio has not yet completed. How can I stop the audio from playing when closing the modal window?

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

You have to use the closing event of the modal, try this

```
$('#myModal').on('hide.bs.modal', function () { //Change #myModal with your modal id
      $('audio').each(function(){
        this.pause(); // Stop playing
        this.currentTime = 0; // Reset time
      }); 
})
```

Answer (score 0):

This is could help you.

```
$("#CmsModal").on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
    $("#CmsModal iframe").attr("src", '');
    $("#CmsModal audio").attr("src", '');
    $("#CmsModal video").attr("src", '');
});
```